# read all shell variables in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, awk, zsh

### Problem:

I'm running shell script as subprocess in ruby script, after running script I want to have an option to check all environment variables of the shell, including array variables.

So far I have come up with:

```
set | awk -F= 'BEGIN            {v=0;}
  /^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*=/    {v=1;}
  v==1 && $2~/^['\''\$]/        {v=2;}
  v==1 && $2~/^\(/              {v=3;}
  v==2 && /'\''$/ && !/'\'\''$/ {v=1;}
  v==3 && /\)$/                 {v=1;}
  v                             {print;}
  v==1                          {v=0;}
'
```

Which quite good shows only variables, including arrays, multiline strings and filtering out functions.

But this does not use the same format all the time, especially array variables are represented differently in BASH and ZSH.

Here is my current implementation: https://github.com/mpapis/tf/blob/master/lib/tf/environment.rb

### Question:

Is there an easy way to show all the variables that will work persistently in BASH and ZSH / possibly other shells.

Comment: Why don't you run `set` or `env` and let Ruby process the output instead of AWK?

Comment: here is ruby part parsing it after awk: https://github.com/mpapis/tf/blob/master/lib/tf/environment.rb#L40-65 - compared to the initial filter in awk: https://github.com/mpapis/tf/blob/master/lib/tf/environment.rb#L23-L32 - there is no single pattern you could use for scanning the output, skipping awk would require also parsing out functions in this already complicated ruby code, but the biggest issue for me is still getting different output for arrays in both BASH and ZSH - see https://github.com/mpapis/tf/blob/master/lib/tf/environment.rb#L6 vs. line 13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice to see you again mpapis ;-)

Unfortunately [arrays and associative arrays are not covered by POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18), and as you have found there are some annoying subtle differences between `bash` and `zsh`.  So there is no single way to do this across all POSIX shells, and we need to check `$BASH_VERSION` etc. as you already noted.

I decided that it was better to avoid having to write Ruby to parse the output of `set` or other `shell` built-ins.  The output is not convenient to parse, and anyway the shell knows the most about its own data, so I thought it made sense to put most of the intelligence inside the shell code.  So instead I have come up with [a solution](https://github.com/aspiers/shell-vars-to-ruby/tree/yaml) which uses shell code to output the data structures as [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), and then that YAML gets loaded directly into Ruby.

First I imported your reference implementation and tests into [the `master` branch of a standalone repository](https://github.com/aspiers/shell-vars-to-ruby).  Then I beefed up the test suite and made a few tweaks.  This showed that there are still issues with the multi-line handling.

Then I created a new [`yaml` branch](https://github.com/aspiers/shell-vars-to-ruby/tree/yaml) and developed my own implementation.  Again I extended the tests.  They all pass ;-)  Notice that I use a few different tricks to do introspection in `zsh` and `bash`:

- `zsh` has a `zsh/parameter` module which provides associative arrays containing the names and types of all its parameters.
- `bash` has `declare -p` which is in an easily parseable form.  It also has `compgen -A variable`, but in the end I didn't use this.

I think it would be easy to add `ksh` support too.

Answer (score 1):

`set` returns all *shell* variables, not environment variables. To get environment variables, use the `env` command. Note that bash does not export arrays to the environment.

Comment: the problem is I'm interested in all the variables, not only what is exported

Comment: I think by definition, a child process can only see what is exported?

Comment: I think he has a Ruby script that includes an embedded shell script, and it is inside that script that he runs `set`. So that shell may have variables in addition to the environment inherited from the Ruby script and, ultimately, the shell that spawned the Ruby script.

Comment: @chepner you are right, additionally I need to see arrays and local variables - whole environment, not only what is exported

Comment: From bash manual I can see that `Environment` is the current state of parameters/functions for executed program, it is separately described from `Execution Environment` which is what child program inherits from it's parrent, and in `Execution Environment` you can see only exported stuff, wile current process `Environment` contains also it's local variables. So `set` displays current process `Environemnt` and `env` displays only **exported** environment, you could say that `env` is a `set` called in subprocess (assuming no additional initialization was done.